# RStudio server RSelenium chrome server error (chrome not reachable) -- but works in SSH R terminal session

Tags: r, selenium, unix, ssh, rstudio-server

I am working with a remote server running Ubuntu 19.10. I'd like to initiate a non-headless chrome server and have developed the following script:

```
require(RSelenium)
eCaps <- list(chromeOptions = list(
  args = c('--window-size=1280,800',
           "--disable-extensions",
           "--use-gl=swiftshader",
           "--user-data-dir=/home/user/.config/google-chrome/Profile1",
           "--remote-debugging-port=9222")
))

# Google Chrome version is 81.0.4044.138 
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome",
               chromever = "81.0.4044.138",
               extraCapabilities = eCaps,
               port = 
                 as.integer(base::sample(seq(32768,65535, by=1),1)))
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

If I log into the box via SSH and start a new R session I can paste the above commands and Chrome server launches with the correct profile and saved passwords required for my purposes.

If, however, I run the exact same commands from RStudio Server this results in an error:

```
Selenium message:unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.3.0-59-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_252'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: #0 0x55918478e189 <unknown>


Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
     Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.
```

Some thoughts:

- I'm only running the selenium server in non-headless mode as I cannot seem to launch Chrome with a saved profile (and saved passwords) when using the `--headless` argument.
- If I use the `--headless` argument as above then the sever can be sucessfully launched both from within RStudio Server and an R terminal session

It feels like a permissions issue, and I have experimented with changing the RStudio Server user to my same username that I SSH into the box with, as per [these instructions](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/217027968-Changing-the-system-account-for-RStudio-Server). This does not resolve the problem.

version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
[Package RSelenium version 1.7.7 Index]

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I'm having the same problem. I'm able to open a Firefox browser via an SSH R terminal session running `rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox")`; when I try the same command in the RStudio server I get a similar error message. I'm also remoting into a Ubuntu server.

Comment: No, I couldn't resolve this -- ended up sinking too many hours into it